# Add device classes to body w jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Could someone help me out. I don't know why I can't get this to work :) Maybe I'm just tired.

Anyhow I'd like to add to body similar classes that boostrap3 uses (col-sm, col-md, col-lg) but i don't think the widths are working correctly...

```
function body_classes() {

    var current_width = $(window).width();
    if (current_width < 481) $('body').addClass("body-sm").removeClass("body-md").removeClass("body-lg");
    else if (current_width < 992) $('body').addClass("body-md").removeClass("body-sm").removeClass("body-lg");
    else $('body').addClass("body-lg").removeClass("body-sm").removeClass("body-md");

}
```

Comment: The code is working fine, are you calling `body_classes()` anywhere?

Comment: maybe you call body_classes before the body element is available. Place your script on the end of the page

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but make sure it's called *after* the DOM is ready.

I've fixed/updated your code for anyone who comes here looking for this functionality.

- Make sure the DOM is ready
- Update class on browser resize
- Adds all *4* Bootstrap classes
- Replaced the `removeClass()`'es with a single empty call, which removes all classes.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).resize(function() {
        addScreenWidthClasses();
    });

    function addScreenWidthClasses() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) 
            $('body')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('screen-xs');
        else if ($(window).width() < 992) 
            $('body')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('screen-sm');
        else if ($(window).width() < 1200) 
            $('body')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('screen-md');
        else 
            $('body')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('screen-lg');
    }
}
```